# Failed to Build Boost With devtoolsets-8-gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, centos7, devtoolset

I tried to build Boost 1.71.0:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost -with-toolset=gcc
```

And it gave:

```
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... 
Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
$ cat bootstrap.log 
B2_TOOLSET is gcc, but the 'gcc' command cannot be executed.
Make sure 'gcc' is in PATH, or use a different toolset.
```

However, gcc is indeed in `PATH`:

```
$ which gcc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/gcc
$ echo $PATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/hc/.local/bin:/home/hc/bin
```

I wonder what goes wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

./bootstrap.sh is going to build the boost.build tool called b2, and install it at your prefix

Software collections work on a per user basis, so it might not work correctly with sudo. You can try to elevate to root with `sudo -i` , turn on devtoolset-8 with `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` then attempt to build b2 and the rest of boost from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried to run `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost -with-toolset=gcc` as root.  Same issue.  devtoolset-8 has been enabled.  Any idea?

Comment: Since that didn't work, I suspect that the script `./bootstrap.sh` is looking for gcc in the normal places, despite the PATH variable being set correctly. 

Another thing you could try is to add the line `source scl_source enable devtoolset-8` to the top of the `bootstrap.sh`. I've had some success with that in the past. [This article has some good information as well.](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703)